# getting Public IP and other text based info from http://ip.zscaler.com/

Tags: python, python-3.x

With these 2 Python commands, I can get Public IP easily.

```
>>> get('https://ident.me').text
'1.2.3.4'
>>>

>>> urllib.request.urlopen('https://ident.me').read().decode('utf8')
'1.2.3.4'
>>>
```

However, when I change the URL from https://ident.me to http://ip.zscaler.com/, I'm getting too many unnessary HTML info.

I'm only interested with the following text based information as shown in the screenshot below.

**Test Proxy 1**
[image: Test Proxy 1]

**Test Proxy 2**
[image]

**Test Proxy 3**
[image]

Would it be possible to get only the important text based information from http://ip.zscaler.com/ and remove other unnecessary HTML tag?

**Desired Output**

```
>>> get('http://ip.zscaler.com/').text
The request received from you did not have an XFF header, so you are quite likely not going through the Zscaler proxy service.
Your request is arriving at this server from the IP address x.x.x.x
Your Gateway IP Address is most likely x.x.x.x
>>>

>>> urllib.request.urlopen('http://ip.zscaler.com/').read().decode('utf8')
The request received from you did not have an XFF header, so you are quite likely not going through the Zscaler proxy service.
Your request is arriving at this server from the IP address x.x.x.x
Your Gateway IP Address is most likely x.x.x.x
>>>
```

Comment: [Beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is a library that can assist you in extracting information from HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get

URL = "http://ip.zscaler.com/"

# GET request to url 
request = get(URL).text

# Create parser
soup = BeautifulSoup(request, features="html.parser")

# Print out headline
headline = soup.find("div", attrs={"class": "headline"})
print(headline.text)

# Print out details
for detail in soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "details"}):
    print(detail.text)
```

Which gives the following output:

```
The request received from you did not have an XFF header, so you are quite likely not going through the Zscaler proxy service.
Your request is arriving at this server from the IP address 119.17.136.170
Your Gateway IP Address is most likely 119.17.136.170
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use `requests-html` `pip install requests-html` after install the Library

user the code below

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('http://ip.zscaler.com/')
rdata = r.html.find('span', first=True)
print(rdata.text)
```

[image: Python request-html]